# Is it possible to write Google Spreadsheet Script to format data, imported from AdWords?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I understand at Google Sсripts almost nothing, but have a problem that can be solved only by script. Hope for your help:)

I have a Google AdWords script. Using this script I'm importing data into Google sheets. It works one time per month at 7 am (1st of November, 1st of December etc.) The problem is in the format of data it looks like this:
[data has comas and points, but i need whole number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdIsJ.png)

So I have no possibility to work with this data ahead. I need to create a script to convert automatically this data to number format (replace regular expressions "(.0|,)" to " "). And it should work only after table was previously updated by Adwords Script (otherwise all changes will disappear).

Comment: Are you sure the data is not formatted by Google Sheets? Click the field, click Format and see what formatting is selected by Google Sheets.

Comment: Yes, i can do it, but I have a Script that import data from Another system. When it worked - all changes deletes. So I must do it by myself, but i want to automatize it, cose a have a lot of the same sheets.
Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a macro ... you can do it with a simple formula

1. convert commas (thousands seperation) to nothing `=SUBSTITUTE(...;",";"")`
2. convert colon to comma (decimal seperator)`=SUBSTITUTE(...;".";",")`
3. convert string to number `=VALUE(...)`

all above in combination and proper sequence, with source in A1, it looks like

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1;",";"");".";","))
```

If you need a whole number you surround the above with an `=INT()`, `=ROUND()` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it.

But it has some minuses. If I use formula at the same sheet - next time, when adwords script import data, it delete all formulas. So I Import this data with a IMPORTRANGE to another sheet, and use your variant. As a result I have several sheets and It looks disordered.

But it works, so thank you!)))